# How can I get the generic type of the class in dnlib?

Tags: c#, cil, dnlib

I have the following class:

```
public class MyGenericArray<T>
{
    private T[] array;

    public MyGenericArray(int size)
    {
        array = new T[size + 1];
    }

    public T getItem(int index)
    {
        var in2 = index + 1;
        in2 = index - in2;
        index = index + 1 - in2 - 1;
        return array[index];
    }
}
```

I use [dnlib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib) to make some changes at the cil code level.
Inside the `getItem()` method, I want to get the class type of the `this` parameter, `ldarg.0`.

I am looking in the param.Type where

```
param = ((Parameter)_instruction.Operand);
```

I have searched through all the available fields but I could not find it.
In fact, what I get is

```
 ConsoleCalculator.BasicTests/MyGenericArray`1
```

and I expect to find

```
 ConsoleCalculator.BasicTests/MyGenericArray`1<!T>
```

I don't understand why the `<!T>` is missing.

For the field `private T[] array;` the class is displayed correctly, with the `<!T>` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
GenericVar[] genArgs = new GenericVar[typeDef.GenericParameters.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < genArgs.Length; i++)
            genArgs[i] = new GenericVar(i);

GenericInstSig genericInstanceType = new GenericInstSig((ClassOrValueTypeSig) methodDef.DeclaringType.ToTypeSig(), genArgs);
```